# how to output data one time in js

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to output all even and odd elements under each other. They appear many times but I want to see them one time. I mean I need to press `enter` to see elements, but I do not need to do this. How can I solve that?

my code:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
for(var i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
        alert(array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As per the discussion in the comments**, I'm guessing this is what you are looking for:

```
var array = [1,2,3,4];
var array_odd = [];
var array_even = [];

for (var i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    if(array[i] % 2 == 0) {
        array_even.push(array[i]);
    } else {
        array_odd.push(array[i]);
    }
};

// un-comment if you want them 'alerted' as in your code sample
// alert(array_even);
// alert(array_odd);
```

This will give you two arrays, each containing odd/even numbers, **without using the Array 'filter' method, as requested**. 
Though I would recommend the Array.filter() over this implementation.

Comment: Adrici, Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for **.filter** operator

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var oddArr = arr.filter((item) => item % 2 !== 0)
// [1, 3, 5, 7]

var evenArr = arr.filter((item) => item % 2 === 0)
// [2, 4, 6]
```

You said "They appear many times but I want to see them one time".

I assume you want to get rid of the duplicates.

```
var duplicateArray = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7];

var arr = [...new Set(duplicateArray)];
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Or if, by that you meant to alert it directly after computing, instead of alerting individual elements,

then use `alert(oddArr)` followed by `alert(evenArr)`

Answer (score 0):

Please, I will advise you using a filter. it is a high order function meaning it expects a function as it's an argument.

```
 let array = [1,2,3,4]

 let evenNum = array.filter((arrayItems) => arrayItems % 2 === 0);

 let oddNum = array.filter((arrayItems) => arrayItems % 2 !== 0);

 //when you console.log(eventNum) you get 2,4
 //when you console.log(OddNum) you get 1
```